# Evaluate $\lim_{r \to \infty} \iint_{D_r} \frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2} dx dy$

Tags: integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Evaluate
$$\lim_{r \to \infty} \iint_{D_r} \frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2} dx dy$$
where $D_r=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ \text{s.t.} \ 0 \leq y \leq 1, \ x \geq 0, \ x^2+y^2 \leq r^2 \}$.

My try is the following: I use a change of variable in polar coordinates with pole in the origin, hence
$$D_r \mapsto E_r=\{(\rho, \theta) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ \text{s.t.} \ 0 \leq \rho \sin \theta \leq 1, \rho \cos \theta \geq 0, \rho^2 \leq r^2, \rho \geq 0, 0 \leq \theta <2\pi\}$$
$$\iff \left\{(\rho, \theta) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ \text{s.t.} \ 0 \leq \rho \leq \frac{1}{\sin \theta}, 0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}, 0 \leq \rho \leq r\right\}$$
And
$$\lim_{r \to \infty} \iint_{D_r} \frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2} dx dy=\lim_{r \to \infty}\iint_{E_r} \frac{\rho}{1+\rho^2} d \rho d \theta$$
Since $\rho$ has two upper bounds I discuss $0 \leq \rho \leq \min\left(r, \frac{1}{\sin \theta}\right)$. Now, being interested in what happens when $r \to \infty$, I assume that $r>\frac{1}{\sin \theta}$ and so I get that $\min\left(r, \frac{1}{\sin \theta}\right)=\frac{1}{\sin \theta}$; hence
$$\lim_{r \to \infty}\iint_{E_r} \frac{\rho}{1+\rho^2} d \rho d \theta=\lim_{r \to \infty} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\int_0^{\min\left(r,\frac{1}{\sin\theta}\right)} \frac{\rho}{1+\rho^2}d\rho\right)d\theta$$
$$=\lim_{r \to \infty} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sin\theta}} \frac{\rho}{1+\rho^2}d\rho\right)d\theta$$
At this point both the set is independent of $r$ and so
$$\lim_{r \to \infty} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sin\theta}} \frac{\rho}{1+\rho^2}d\rho\right)d\theta=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sin\theta}} \frac{\rho}{1+\rho^2}d\rho\right)d\theta=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{2}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{\sin^2 \theta}\right)d\theta$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{2} \log(1+\sqrt{2})$$
The result is correct, however I'm not sure when I declare that since $r \to \infty$ I can assume $r>\frac{1}{\sin \theta}$; the doubt comes from the fact that $\theta \in \left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ and so when $\theta$ gets really close to $0$ the function $\frac{1}{\sin \theta}$ is unbounded. So I feel like there is some kind of "battle" between $r$ and $\frac{1}{\sin \theta}$ going to infinity that makes impossible to understand which one is actually bigger for discussing the minimum.

Am I missing something and there is no problem for $\frac{1}{\sin \theta}$ when $\theta \to 0^+$ (and if there isn't, why it isn't? Why can I ignore the fact that it tends to infinity for small values of $\theta$ in the domain of integration?) or I was just lucky and my approach was wrong because I can't make that assumption? Thanks.

Edit: Added a term $\frac{1}{2}$ that I forgot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is another way, which avoids the problem you are pointing out. For $r>1$,
$$I_r:=\iint_{D_r} \frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2} dx dy=\int_{0}^1\left(\int_{0}^{\sqrt{r^2-y^2}}\frac{dx}{1+x^2+y^2}\right)\,dy
=\int_{0}^1\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{r^2-y^2}}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\,dy.$$
Now for $y\in[0,1]$ and $r>1$, we have that
$$0\leq \frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{r^2-y^2}}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\right)=\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+y^2}}{\sqrt{r^2-y^2}}\right)\leq
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{r^2-1}}.$$
Hence, as $r\to \infty$,
$$0\leq \frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^1\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}-I_r\leq
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{r^2-1}}\int_0^1\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\leq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{r^2-1}}\to 0,$$
and we may conclude that
$$\lim_{r\to\infty}I_r=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^1\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}=\frac{\pi}{2}\, \log(1+\sqrt{2}).$$

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer, I like it! So there is indeed a problem for $\theta \to 0^+$, I appreciate your answer but the main reason of my question was to understand what is going on for that situation. Could you kindly explain it to me?

Comment: @ZaWarudo I tried a similar approach in polar coordinates, but it seems to be more difficult since we have to control both $\theta$ and $r$.